# Create widget at mouse click

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new at Qt. How can I create a new widget at mouse click? I want to create a new label at every mouse click.

```
// works fine:

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) {
     QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
}
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
     label->setText("Hello");
}

// doesn't work:
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
     QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
     label->setText("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show the widget, and preferably set its position (if not using QLayout):

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setText("Hello");
    label->show();
    label->move(e->pos());
}
```